# How do I undo "defaults write com.apple.dock static-only -bool TRUE; killall Dock" on Mac terminal?

Tags: terminal, osx

I was looking through an article of "clever terminal hacks" to use on Mac.  I did not realize that some of these were irreversible and most of them didn't come with instructions on how to undo them. This particular command

```
defaults write com.apple.dock static-only -bool TRUE
killall Dock
```

makes it so that I can't see apps on my dock that I am not using.

I also used:

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock showhidden -bool TRUE
killall Dock
```

for further damage (it dulls the apps not visible on the screen?). Here is the link to the article for reference : https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/mac-terminal-projects-tutorial-3613813/

Answer (score 2):

The commands you are showing us set variables that govern the behaviour of the MacOS Dock with values that can be changed. Those operands are boolean and can be either TRUE, or FALSE, or YES or NO.

To undo the  MacOS line commands you are showing us, you just have to replace TRUE by FALSE.

So the commands that you need to revert your operations are:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock static-only -bool FALSE
defaults write com.apple.Dock showhidden -bool FALSE
killall Dock
```

PS. I advise *against* blindly experimenting random commands from the Internet without firstly trying to understand the effects in the system and how they can be undone.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Rui. It won't work for some reason though. Terminal answers with "Unexpected argument kilaall; leaving defaults unchanged."

Comment: Kilaall is not killall?